# Ordenar por nombre en Java

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: Clase Cliente][image: Necesito ordenar este código por nombre, he tratado pero solo puedo ordenarlo por identificación, si me ayudan lo agradeceria mucho.]
Adjunto imagenes del código, gracias.

Comment: Estimado @Santiago, procura no colocar enlaces a recursos externos para mostrar tu código, en su lugar agrega el código como texto y le das el formato de bloque de código!. Revisa el [tour] para que sepas como funciona SOes y aprendas [ask]. Dale [edit] para que corrijas estos puntos!

Comment: El comentario de @GmrYael fue claro. Sube el código como texto. Así es más fácil copiarlo para probarlo.

Comment: [es.so] te da las herramientas necesarias para subir el código _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Además, explica el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo. Lee [ask].

Comment: Cuál es la pregunta? Si te respondemos con imágenes de código, te gustaría?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El problema que yo veo, es que el while que tienes para recorrer la lista y agregar el nuevo nodo, la comparacion de las cadenas las haces con

while(aux != null && nue.getCedula() > aux.getCedula())

El contenido de los string no se puede comparar con = > o <

Para eso existe el metodo compareTo, el cual te pongo 3 ejemplos:

```
        System.out.println( "ZAMORA".compareToIgnoreCase("FABIO")); // Resultado 20
        System.out.println( "FABIO".compareToIgnoreCase("ZAMORA")); // Resultado -20
        System.out.println( "FABIO".compareToIgnoreCase("FaBiO")); // Resultado 0
```

Cuando las cadenas son iguales regresa 0, cuando la cadena inicial es menor, regresa un numero menor a 0 y cuando la cadena inicial es mayor, regresa un numero mayor a 0.

El primer cambio que realizara es la condicion del while:

```
while(aux != null && nue.getCedula().compareToIgnoreCase(aux.getCedula()) > 0)
```

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/3217#3217